# travis ci build failing - cause: PermGen space

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci, kotlin

I created a android application with Kotlin and I added Travis CI support in the repo.
The build is always failing.

Cause: PermGen space

What does it mean? My .travis.yml file is

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-23.0.2
    - android-23
```

Comment: what version of the JDK?  can you change to build on JDK 8, even though you are targetting android it is allowed.  Then you don't have to adjust permgen, otherwise you need to give more permgen space to gradle.  This is not a Kotlin issue, more of a Gradle issue.

Comment: @JaysonMinard this is an android build as described in config. https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.

I changed my .travis.yml file adding:

```
env:
- GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Answer (score 2):

[PermGen Space described here](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/permgen-space).

I suggest to add this lines into your `build.gradle` to increse size of permgen for tests:

```
test {
    jvmArgs "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
}
```

Comment: in which file i should add these lines? in /build.gradle or /app/build.gradle? and in where of the file? here're the files: http://pastebin.com/n5sHAjtR  http://pastebin.com/Y5VX49rb 
sorry, but i'm not an expert with gradle

Comment: Looks like you should add these lines into  /app/build.gradle

Comment: @user3744384 top level, unless you have you subprojects (which I doubt).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Java 8 to avoid PermGen trouble altogether. Add this to your .travis.yml:

```
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```